How to connect Azure Postgre Server to Google Looker Studio
I am trying to connect the database via the postgre connector on looker studio. However, I'm getting an error:
Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.
Error ID: 8ccc5e3b
I've confirmed the credentials of the database and the IP has been whitelisted. I've managed to connect to it successfully through pgadmin. I've successfully tested using a render database. With render it required me to use the ISRG Root certificate from let's encrypt. Because this one is Azure I used the one Microsoft provided here

As per the documentation, to allow the looker studio to connect to the azure PostgreSQL database, you will need to whitelist the below IP addresses.

142.251.74.0/23

2001:4860:4807::/48 (for platforms that support IPv6)


Once you have added the IP address, you should be able to connect to your database from Looker Studio without any issues.
Reference: Connect to PostgreSQL - Looker Studio Help (google.com)
